# Most efficient VHDL for large vector?

Tags: vhdl

I want to be able to have a shift register that does an XOR against another register loaded with some value. The issue is that I wish to do this with a large scale vector, something on the order of thousands of bits wide.

The obvious way to do this in VHDL would be something like

```
generic( length : integer := 15);

signal shiftreg : std_logic_vector(length downto 0);


process(clk) 
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        shiftreg<= shiftreg(length-1 downto 0) & input;
    endif;
end process;
```

However, if length here is set to some very high number, attempting to synthesize this becomes a massive undertaking. Since this is a relatively simple structure I imagine it is taking so long because the length is far beyond the number of registers in a single block.

My question is if there is some way to implement a large vector like this in a way that would be quicker to synthesize. For example, is it quicker to use something like

```
array(length downto 0) of std_logic;
```

or does a synthesis tool recognize those are equivalent?

Comment: You might consider constructing your 'thousands of bits wide' shift register out of a smaller instantiated shift register, a cookie cutter approach where the basic mapping is done once. You haven't demonstrated how `shiftreg` is used which could affect place and route. Is there any way of expressing locality for operations associated with parts of `shiftreg`?

Comment: The shiftreg is used in an XOR to another equal sized register, as I mentioned, and then the bits of that XOR is summed to give the number of non-matching bits.

Comment: Can you operate both registers as shift registers and count the number of non-matching bits as you shift in?  How are you doing this summing now? The idea is not reduce the complexity to the function. A single XOR gate and a counter instead of some larger summing mechanism. You haven't describe how complex the entire 'thing' being synthesized is.

Comment: At the moment there is no complexity. I plan on eventually implementing the adder to sum the XORed bits, but right now it is just 3 std_logic_vectors, 2 to hold data, and 1 to eventally hold the XOR result. Just having those 3 vectors and using the update process described in my question is what is causing the long synthesis time I am seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synthesis time is not typically relevant in FPGA design, although area utilization and timing usually is. If your shift register takes most of the resources that your target FPGA has, synthesis will take a long time trying to figure out a way to make it work, and likewise builds take longer as you fill up larger parts. For some ballpark, an 80% full design with tight timing in a modern midrange FPGA usually takes about 30 minutes to synthesize and 3 hours to place&route. This will not be significantly affected by coding style if you're still describing the same functionality.

If you describe a shift register (with the same functional features) in VHDL using std_logic_vector, a type you defined as an array of std_logic, or anything else, it will synthesize into the same thing.

In recent-ish Xilinx parts at least, a single LUT can be used for a 64-deep shift register as long as you haven't described a reset (synchronous OR asynchronous). You can likewise produce a 1000 deep shift register with just a handful of LUTs.

Now if you're looking to use the whole thousand+ bits of this shift register to xor against some other register, you can't use SRLs (LUT used as a shift register) because only the final bit is accessible as an output. This makes it put the whole thing in registers which may be rather large, and could require more registers than your part has. The key thing here is that you have to think about the scale of the hardware you describe, and whether that's feasible in your target part.

If you want a really deep shift register, block rams can be used to act like shift registers at depths exceeding 100,000 but these have the same issue where you only access the final output.

Comment: Your comment on typical timing matches my general experience with VHDL, but not what I'm seeing with this example. For a vector of say 2^16 bits, I should be using about 1/4 of the FF available on the FPGA, according to the Post-Synthesis Utilization report, but it is taking well over 4 hours just to synthesize, without even attempting Implementation.

Comment: @Zephyr it does sound like you could be encountering a case where the synthesizer isn't doing quite what it should. Is there anything else in the design besides the shift register? I assume it's not being optimized away, so there has to be something, and anything you do to the whole vector will consume an enormous quantity of LUTs, so you could still be running out of resources. Nevertheless I urge you to rethink your approach if you need a 64k deep shift register with access to every bit for further logic.

Comment: At the moment I have 2 shift registers implemented as described in my question, and 1 other std_logic_vector of the same size that will hold the result. Eventually I will XOR the 2 shift registers into the vector, and sum the bits of the result vector, but I don't have that implemented yet, and I am hitting this large synthesis time with just 3 large vectors.

Comment: You might try having one shift register that's input is the XOR of your two input bits. It will end up being the same as your result register but much, much cheaper. You also might try having the input to your now single shift register add to an accumulator, then subtract the output at the end of the shift register. Now you have the sum of "1" bits with just two adders (instead of thousands which would be unbelievably expensive) and because you don't need access to the intermediate bits of the shift register it can be implemented in a single BRAM. Bam, now its cheap.

Comment: The two shift registers use different clocks. So register 1 will shift in new data for a few cycles, then it will hold and register 2 will shift in new data for a few cycles. Therefore the two do not have a consistent alignment, so I can't just XOR the bits as they come in.

Comment: My main question as to whether or not the syntax of how I write VHDL would affect how it gets synthesized has been answered though, so I'm accepting your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I see there are complications on setting it up exactly as I threw it out, but I still think there are architecture changes that you can make to make this much more realistic. If you wish, I'd have no problem hashing out a workable architecture in chat when I get home in a few minutes.

Comment: Well I have to leave soon so I don't have the time today, but I'll take your advice and try redesigning how I set this up.