# Handling very large vector in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, synthesis

Similiarly to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641381/most-efficient-vhdl-for-large-vector), I face issues managing very large vectors in FPGA, and nothing really helped in the previous topic. I have a 2^15 bits wide sample, I want to make something similar to an bitwise autocorrelation of this sample by shifting-xoring-adding all the bits of this vector.

One of my constraints is a fast exectution time (less than 100ms with a 12MHz clock).

My way to do it for now is using an FSM in which one state is responsible for processing each iteration of the bitwise autocorrelation, and a following step comparing the current result to the minimum value so far (the minimum value reflecting the fundamental frequency of the sample). To do so, I use a for loop (not a big fan of this kind of structure usually...). Here is a piece of my code :

```
when S_BACF => 
    count_ones :=(others=>'0');
    for i in 0 to 32766 loop
        count_ones := count_ones + (sample(i) xor sample((index+i) mod 32767));
    end loop;
    s_nb_of_ones_current <= count_ones;
    current_state <= S_COMP;                      
when S_COMP => 
    if index >= 19999 then
        index <=0;
        current_state <= S_END;
    else
        index <= index+1;
        current_state <= S_BACF;
        if s_nb_of_ones_saved > s_nb_of_ones_current then
            s_nb_of_ones_saved <= s_nb_of_ones_current;
            s_min_rank <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(index,15));
        end if;
    end if;
```

Sorry I don't define each signal/variable, but I think it is transparent enough. My index doesn't need to go beyond 20000 (for this application).

I think this way of processing data is quite efficient in registers use ("just" one vector of 2^15 bits and a 15-bits vector for the fundamental frequency).

In simulation, it works great. BUT, as expected, the synthesis fails, even for quite big targets. The for loop, though efficient in theory cannot be synthesised with such a big depth.

I imagined splitting my data into several smaller pieces, but the shifting-xoring operation through different smaller vectors is a nightmare.

I also thought about using the internal RAM of my FPGA to save my sample, in order to reduce the register usage, but it won't be effective against the for loop synthesis issue.

So, do any of you have a good idea for the synthesis to be successfull?

Comment: I wonder - how much design did you do before you wrote any VHDL? did you think about the circuit before the code? did you draw an architectural diagram and or concept of how the design would work?

Comment: Your question does not provide a VHDL problem statement - the problem seems to be a problem of design, not code. I recommend you post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) re-stating the problem.

Comment: Consider using the relationship `n % 2^i = n & (2^i - 1)` for modulo operations when divisor is power of two.

Comment: What do you expect from the `S_BACF` case? You are assigning a signal twice, outside and inside the for loop. What do you think is going to happen in the real hardware?

Comment: @Tricky I carefully think about the algorithm, draw many timing diagrams and fsm. I did not foresee the hardware occupation though. Moreover I did not provide an MCVE since it seemed to me to be a synthesis issue and not coding issue and is very target dependent.

Comment: @Fra93 I actually re-code this specific line using the fact that an all-ones vector "reset" to 0 when '1' is added. As for the double assignment, it concerns a variable and not a signal. But for robustness considerations, I re-coded this as well.

Comment: To all : I managed to synthesis my design by splitting the for loop into several parts, keeping a low processing time. It is a ressource issue.